# Javascript Timer Runs Sporadically

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am developing a messaging system and through discussion here: [webBrowser.Document.Write() Irregular Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591918/webbrowser-document-write-irregular-performance) I decided to rewite some of the core login in my program in Javascript.

The demo seen here: http://nathantornquist.com/code/misc/index6.html runs perfectly when you are adding messages from John.
As soon as you add a message from Jack, the timer gets messed up and the color of the date on John's messages stop changing.

Can anyone see a clear reason why?

Comment: The elusive quote character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the console in Firefox or Chrome? I checked it out and got an error when clicking "Add a message from Jack"

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: black is not defined
switchColorindex6.html:74
(anonymous function)
```

Is black a variable that should be defined?

Comment: Ha, that was it.  I forgot that you can't use the standard html color names there.  It works perfectly now.  Thanks.

Comment: @NathanTornquist Perhaps mark this nice post as the answer to you question?

Answer (score 0):

On lines 74 and 76 you have black not quoted, e.g.

```
        if (!elements[i].style.color!=black)
```

Try quoting it:

```
        if (!elements[i].style.color!="black")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in lines 72-78. One is that you compare color to `black` which is undefined. Probably it should be `'black'`. Second is `elements[i].stlye` on line 76.