# How do I set an embedded html file as the page to navigate to in a webBrowser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html, webbrowser-control

I have a live webpage that will act as the output of my program.

I would like to include the source html file and have the browser navigate to that for initialization instead of putting the entire html source code into a hard coded string.

Any ideas?

Comment: what are your real intentions then for this type of request sounds a bit suspecious in nature..

Comment: I am developing a messaging program. The output of the program is displayed in a webBrowser control so that I have full control over the way that the output looks.  In response to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595125/javascript-timer-runs-sporadically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591918/webbrowser-document-write-irregular-performance I decided that I would rather embed the html instead of putting it in as a string so that it is easier to read and modify in the future.  It is not suspicious.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `DocumentText` property to your source string.

For better performance, set `Document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml` instead.
(You may need to load a dummy document first)

Comment: That's what I would like to do.  I just want a way to load the source string from the html file and embed it in the project, instead of converting it to a string on my own and just putting that in as a constant.

Comment: @NathanTornquist: Are you asking how to read an embedded resource? That's a totally separate question.

Comment: Note that you cannot use this approach with images.

Comment: I think I might be asking that.  I tried doing this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292 and I get an "Error Accessing Resources" message.  Something doesn't quite work right.

Comment: --Nevermind. I got it to work. That Microsoft resource and your answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to save embedded html into the temp directory and then navigate to that saved file address.

Comment: I will not have access to data outside of the program.  Saving to a temp directory may not be possible depending on the server permissions of my clients.

Comment: @NathanTornquist: It should always be possible to write to `%TEMP%`

Comment: @SLaks, I can certainly try that.  It seems silly that you can't navigate to an included file though.  That would be incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to open your embedded file as stream and then use
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostream.aspx

NavigateToStreamMethod of a webbrowser!